# Is there a Python function for finding each section of "Area Under curve"?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to calculate Area under curve("A1", "A2", "A3", which is sliced by red line, first row graph) using Python packages (simps, trapz).

The problem is that the result of "A2"(second row graph, "Area2") is partially drawn unlike what I expected. **How can I cut out "A2"**(not "Area2") to calculate the area of ​​the section?

Lastly, does anyone know how to **calculate absolute area ignoring negative y-axis values(A3)**?

```
a1y = [-731.11059984, -728.47093717, -713.86716911, -680.2975881 ,
       -618.76047483, -524.25410195, -396.7767379 , -240.32665095,
        -63.9021133 ,  122.49859465,  306.87718006,  478.23533331,
        630.57472375,  757.89699553,  849.20376345,  912.49660913,
        966.77707721, 1008.04667182, 1037.30685332, 1055.55903521,
       1065.80458132]
a1x = np.arange(len(a1y))

a2y=[1069.04480327, 1068.2809582 , 1064.51424672, 1057.74581119,
       1048.97673424, 1038.20803754, 1023.44068087, 1004.67556141,
        983.91351339,  959.15530785,  928.40165277,  890.65319339,
        844.9105128 ,  791.17413276,  730.4445147 ,  664.72206101,
        596.00711644,  526.29996976,  465.60085552,  409.90995604,
        354.22740345,  302.5532819 ,  256.88762985]
a2x= np.arange(len(a2y))

a3y=[ 216.23044249,  181.58167415,  149.94124091,  121.30902312,
         94.68486807,   69.06859264,   42.45998605,   14.85881254,
        -10.73518588,  -35.32228663,  -63.90278387,  -94.47698566,
       -127.0452113 , -160.60778851, -194.16505079, -227.71733472,
       -261.26497733, -294.8083135 , -327.34767345, -358.88338026,
       -385.41574752, -407.94507695, -433.47165627, -459.99575703,
       -486.51763258, -513.03751622, -537.55561935, -561.07212984,
       -582.58721047, -603.10099754, -622.61359958, -640.12509628,
       -657.63553747, -670.14494237, -681.6532989 , -696.16056319,
       -711.66665933, -727.17147916, -742.67488235, -758.17669657,
       -773.67671795, -789.17471161, -804.67041247, -821.16352618,
       -837.65373036, -849.1406759 , -855.62398858]
a3x=np.arange(len(a3y))

wave = [-731.11059984, -728.47093717, -713.86716911, -680.2975881 ,
       -618.76047483, -524.25410195, -396.7767379 , -240.32665095,
        -63.9021133 ,  122.49859465,  306.87718006,  478.23533331,
        630.57472375,  757.89699553,  849.20376345,  912.49660913,
        966.77707721, 1008.04667182, 1037.30685332, 1055.55903521,
       1065.80458132, 1069.04480327, 1068.2809582 , 1064.51424672,
       1057.74581119, 1048.97673424, 1038.20803754, 1023.44068087,
       1004.67556141,  983.91351339,  959.15530785,  928.40165277,
        890.65319339,  844.9105128 ,  791.17413276,  730.4445147 ,
        664.72206101,  596.00711644,  526.29996976,  465.60085552,
        409.90995604,  354.22740345,  302.5532819 ,  256.88762985,
        216.23044249,  181.58167415,  149.94124091,  121.30902312,
         94.68486807,   69.06859264,   42.45998605,   14.85881254,
        -10.73518588,  -35.32228663,  -63.90278387,  -94.47698566,
       -127.0452113 , -160.60778851, -194.16505079, -227.71733472,
       -261.26497733, -294.8083135 , -327.34767345, -358.88338026,
       -385.41574752, -407.94507695, -433.47165627, -459.99575703,
       -486.51763258, -513.03751622, -537.55561935, -561.07212984,
       -582.58721047, -603.10099754, -622.61359958, -640.12509628,
       -657.63553747, -670.14494237, -681.6532989 , -696.16056319,
       -711.66665933, -727.17147916, -742.67488235, -758.17669657,
       -773.67671795, -789.17471161, -804.67041247, -821.16352618,
       -837.65373036, -849.1406759 , -855.62398858]
```

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import trapz, simps       


fig=plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(wave)
plt.title('Area under curve')

plt.subplot(2, 3, 4)
plt.plot(a1x,a1y)
plt.title('Area 1')

plt.subplot(2, 3, 5)
plt.plot(a2x,a2y)
plt.title('Area 2')

plt.subplot(2, 3, 6)
plt.plot(a3x,a3y)
plt.title('Area 3')

print ("Area under curve", simps(wave, np.arange(len(wave)))
print("area under graph A1", simps(a1y, a1x))
print("area under graph A2", simps(a2y, a2x))
print("area under graph A3", simps(a3y, a3x))
```

[image]

Does anyone know how to how to calculate "A2" (not "Area2")??

[image]

Comment: It is not entirely clear how A2 is defined, but it seems that A2 is Area2 minus the first value from A3. So just subtract that value.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking for. Do you want to have your subplots show the same wider range on the y-axis, rather than each scaling to their own height? Or do you think your area calculations are incorrect for some reason? Areas under a curve are generally signed, so there's an implicit horizontal line at y=0 below which the area *above* the curve (between it an zero) is what you're counting, as a negative. If you don't want that, you should probably clamp your data to zero if it's lower, which will dramatically change the results you get for A1 and A3 (but probably not A2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want to calculate the area of the curve between the horizontal line defined by the min value of wave and the curve for each chunk?

Just subtract the min value:

```
M = min(wave)
print("Area under curve", simps(np.array(wave)-M, np.arange(len(wave))))
print("area under graph A1", simps(np.array(a1y)-M, a1x))
print("area under graph A2", simps(np.array(a2y)-M, a2x))
print("area under graph A3", simps(np.array(a3y)-M, a3x))
```

output:

```
Area under curve 81497.49533938
area under graph A1 21437.511782499998
area under graph A2 36243.834408466675
area under graph A3 20800.25109029666
```

*NB. the total is of the three areas is slightly less than the total area because you're skipping two fine bands between the three chunks. To avoid that, ensure the last point of one chunk is the first one of the next chunk.*

With consecutive intervals:

```
Area under curve 81497.49533938
area under graph A1 23361.64246073833
area under graph A2 36243.834408466675
area under graph A3 21891.767255634997
```